# Ruby - gem install escape_utils fails with errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I tried to install the

**`gem install escape_utils -v '0.3.2'`**

it gives me following errors which I don't know how to fix 
I am using

```
ruby --version 
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]

rails -v
Could not find escape_utils-0.3.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

The error I get when trying to install is

```
gem install escape_utils -v '0.3.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing escape_utils:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150613-4082-zkyiyc.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling houdini_xml_e.c
compiling buffer.c
compiling escape_utils.c
escape_utils.c: In function ‘rb_eu_escape_html_as_html_safe’:
escape_utils.c:126: error: assignment of read-only member ‘klass’
make: *** [escape_utils.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/escape_utils-0.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/escape_utils-0.3.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are attempting to install v0.3.2? You may have better luck using a more recent release https://rubygems.org/gems/escape_utils

Comment: Did you look in the log in `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/escape_utils-0.3.2/gem_make.out`? It might tell you more about the error.

Comment: I need this to install the open source billing app. Its asking me to install the version.

Comment: I did look at the make out error but no additional information

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with escape_utils itself. You should edit Gemfile.lock file and change `escape_utils (0.3.2)` to `escape_utils (1.1.0)`.